# Advantages of using std::make_unique over new operator

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

What are the advantages of using `std::make_unique` over the `new` operator for initializing a `std::unique_ptr`?

In other words, why is

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> a = std::make_unique(SomeObject(...))
```

better than doing

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> a = new SomeObject(...)
```

I tried looking up a lot online and I do know that it is a good rule of thumb to avoid the operator `new` in modern C++, but I am not sure what the advantages are in this exact scenario. Does it prevent any kind of memory leaks that might happen? Is it faster to do a `std::make_unique` than to use `new`?

Comment: Actually `std::make_unique(SomeObject(...))` results in calling constructor and copy/move constructor. Definitely, a better choice is to call `std::make_unique` directly with construtor parameters of underlying templated type.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

### Advantages

- `make_unique` teaches users "never say `new`/`delete` and
  `new[]`/`delete[]`" without disclaimers.
- `make_unique` shares two advantages with `make_shared` (excluding the third advantage, increased efficiency). First, `unique_ptr<LongTypeName> up(new LongTypeName(args))` must mention `LongTypeName` twice, while `auto up = make_unique<LongTypeName>(args)` mentions it once.
- `make_unique` prevents the unspecified-evaluation-order
  leak triggered by expressions like `foo(unique_ptr<X>(new X), unique_ptr<Y>(new Y))`. (Following the advice "never say `new`" is simpler than
  "never say `new`, unless you immediately give it to a named `unique_ptr`".)
- `make_unique` is carefully implemented for exception safety and is recommended over directly calling `unique_ptr` constructors.

### When not to use `make_unique`

- Don't use `make_unique` if you need a custom deleter or are adopting a raw pointer from elsewhere.

### Sources

1. [Proposal of `std::make_unique`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt).
2. [Herb Sutter's GotW #89 Solution: Smart Pointers](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain the reasoning for your point on when not to use it, please?

Comment: There's one additional case when not to use make_unique: In case of private or protected constructors!
Please absent from listening to any suggestions on SO or the net recommending to make make_unique or unique_ptr or whatever a friend of your class. This is non-portable (as then you depend on the implementation details of unique_ptr and stuff). And it breaks the privateness of the constructor (that should have a reason to be private) as afterwards anybody could make_unique<PrivateClass>!

Comment: I'm curious the same as this comment on Herb Sutter's writeup on this same topic https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/#comment-5725. Essentially what if such `make_unique` is inlined (let's assume it is), then the equivalent call to function which accepts multiple arguments won't have exception safety anymore?

Comment: @haxpor The exception safety bases on the lifetime of objects which has nothing to do with optimizations like inlining. Your so called "equivalent call to function" is not equivalent since it does not take the scope of the function body of  `make_unique<...>` into account.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd point. Unfortunately make_unique does not seem to have robust support for initializer lists. So `unique_ptr<TypeWithDeepMap>(new TypeWithDeepMap({}))` turns to `make_unque<TypeWithDeepMap>(std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>({}))`

Comment: The _unspecified-evaluation-order leak_ problem [has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870522/why-use-stdmake-unique-in-c17) as it is specified as of C++17.

Comment: Here is the additional but similar resource: https://isocpp.org/blog/2019/06/quick-q-differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new

Comment: Disadvantage: make_unique requires the constructor to be public, so if you’ve declared it protected so it can only be called by a friend factory function then you’re sunk.

Answer (score 96):

The difference is that [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) returns an object of type [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and `new` returns a pointer to the created object. For memory allocation failures, they will both throw. **Hold on, it's not that simple. Read further.**

Consider such a function below:

```
void func(ClassA* a, ClassB* b){
     ......
}
```

When you make a call like `func(new A(), new B())`; The compiler may choose to evaluate the function arguments from left to right, or in any order it so wishes. Let's assume left to right evaluation: What happens when the first `new` expression succeeds but the second `new` expression throws?

The real danger here is when you catch such exception; Yes, you may have caught the exception thrown by `new B()`, and resume normal execution, but `new A()` already succeeded, and its memory will be silently leaked. Nobody to clean it up... * *sobs*...

But with `make_unique`, you cannot have a leak because, stack unwinding will happen ( and the destructor of the previously created object will run). Hence, having a preference for `make_unique` will constrain you towards [*exception safety*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). In this case, `std::make_unique` provides a ["*Basic Exception Safety*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) that the memory allocated and object created by `new` will never be orphaned no matter what. Even till the ends of time... :-)

You should read [Herb Sutter GoTW102](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)

Comment: @Nik-Lz `func(new A(), new B())` doesn't make a `unique_ptr`, the answer was about what happens when you don't use it...

Comment: Points for clearly explaining what issue arises from poor exception handling in response to using new. The first answer hints towards the exception safety justification, but doesn't make it clear. Both new and make_unique throw exceptions, but only make_unique handles freeing the memory upon destruction.