# C++ working with objects on heap

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, shared-ptr, raw-pointer

I am currently learning C++, coming from C#/Java background, using visual studio 2017.

I have a question in regards to creating objects on heap and referencing them properly down the road. So far I came across multiple tutorials and ways of doing things. Some recommend using smart pointers as much as possible, others swear its [the devils tool](http://www.codingwisdom.com/codingwisdom/2012/09/reference-counted-smart-pointers-are-for-retards.html).

My current main looks like this:

```
//Main
Person *makePerson()
{
    string name;
    int age;
    cout << "Input name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Input age: ";
    cin >> age;
    return new Person(name, age);
}

Child *makeChild(Person &parent)
{
    return new Child(*makePerson(), &parent);;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "---Input parent data---" << endl;
    Person *person = makePerson();
    cout << "printing: " << *person << endl;
    cout << "---Input child data---" << endl;
    Child *child = makeChild(*person);
    cout << "printing: " << *child << endl;
    cout << "---end of main---" << endl;
    delete person;
    delete child;
    return 0;
}
```

A function handles input of personal data and returns a pointer to new Person object. Then I have a function that handles creation of child object by taking a parent reference and asking makePerson for remaining data.

Can this be considered good C++? How can I make it better? I would really appreciate some code examples.

As some have already suggested, I could replace raw pointers with either `shared_ptr<Person> person` (heavy) or `unique_ptr<Person>` (better than shared).

This is code for Person and child classes. Note that Child has a raw pointer of type `Person *parent`.

```
//header
class Person
{
protected: 
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person();
    Person(const Person& other);
    Person(std::string inName, int inAge);
    ~Person();
    virtual void print() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    int getAge() const;
    Person &operator=(const Person &other);
    //overload print functionality, act as if it was toString
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Person &p);
};
//cpp
Person::Person() : name(""), age(0) {
    std::cout << "Person empty constructor" << std::endl;
}

Person::Person(std::string inName, int inAge) : name(inName), age(inAge) {
    std::cout << "Person (" << name << ") default constructor" << std::endl;
}

Person::Person(const Person & other) : name(other.name), age(other.age) {
    std::cout << "Person (" << name << ") copy constructor" << std::endl;
}

Person::~Person() {
    std::cout << "Person (" << name << ") destructor" << std::endl;
}

void Person::print() const {
    std::cout << name << ", " << age << std::endl;
}

std::string Person::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

int Person::getAge() const
{
    return age;
}

Person & Person::operator=(const Person & other) {
    std::cout << "Person (" << other.name << ") assignment constructor" << std::endl;
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    return *this;
}
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Person &p) {
    return out << p.name << ", " << p.age;
}
```

A child is a person and it makes sense for a child to have knowledge of who childs parent is. However, am uncertain how to handle this "knowledge". Here is code I am using for child class:

```
//Header
class Child : public Person
{
private:
    const Person *parent;
public:
    Child();
    Child(std::string name, int age);
    Child(std::string name, int age, const Person *parent);
    Child(const Child &child, const Person *parent);
    Child(const Person &person);
    ~Child();
    Child &operator=(const Child &other);
    void print() const;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Child &c);
};
//cpp
Child::Child() {
    std::cout << "Child empty constructor" << std::endl;
}

Child::Child(std::string name, int age) : Person(name, age), parent(nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Orphan (" << name << ") constructor" << std::endl;
}

Child::Child(std::string name, int age, const Person *parent) :
    Person(name, age), parent(parent) {
    std::cout << "Child (" << name << ") default constructor" << std::endl;
}

Child::Child(const Child &child, const Person *parent) : 
    Person(child.name, child.age), parent(parent) {
    std::cout << "Child (" << child.name << ") copy constructor" << std::endl;
}

Child::Child(const Person &person) : Person(person), parent(nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Child from person (" << name << ") constructor" << std::endl;
}

Child::~Child() {
    std::cout << "Child (" << name << ") destructor" << std::endl;
}

Child & Child::operator=(const Child & other) {
    name = other.name;
    age = other.age;
    parent = other.parent;
    std::cout << "Child (" << name << ") assignment constructor" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}

void Child::print() const {
    if(parent)
        std::cout << *this << " is child of " << *parent << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << *this << " is orphan" << std::endl;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Child &c) {
    return out << c.name << ", " << c.age << " is " << 
        (c.parent ? ("child of " + c.parent->getName() + ", " + std::to_string(c.parent->getAge())) : "orphan");
}
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

I suppose my question still remains, could anyone give me an example of how it should look like to be considered good C++?

@user4581301 if you take a look at the updated main, do you mean I should return a `std::unique_ptr`instead of a `* (raw pointer)`? In which case my function will look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Person> makePerson2()
{
    string name;
    int age;
    cout << "Input name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Input age: ";
    cin >> age;
    return std::unique_ptr<Person>(new Person(name, age));
}
```

And variable declaration as:

```
std::unique_ptr<Person> upParent = makePerson2();
cout << "printing: " << *upParent << endl;
```

Would this be considered "better" C++ than what I have so far?

Comment: Yes, `std::shared_ptr` is heavy, but, the times you will need it are pretty small.  In most cases `std::unique_ptr` is what you really want and in most cases it is a zero overhead abtraction.

Comment: `string *s = new string("Hello world");` in most cases you don't want to do this with std::string.

Comment: Regarding the edits and `makePerson2`: Yes. That would be better, but if you have a C++14 compiler Prefer `return std::make_unique<Person>(name, age);` as [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) eliminates a [few more possible error cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-make-unique-over-new-operator)

Answer (score 5):

I think that one of the most important thing to know about C++ *especially if you come from Java/C# background* is:

***Objects are value-types by default, not reference type!***

you entire code could have been written as simply:

```
int main()
{
    //this work
    Person person("John Doe", 22); 
    //this work
    Child child("Johnny Doe", 2, person);
    cout << "---end of main---" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See how the code turned into nothing? you don't have to worry about allocations, deleting unused object etc. because **objects are not reference type to begin with!**

My personal hierarchy of rules go:

1. use objects as value types as much as possible. pass them by reference to avoid copies. make sure a valid move constructor is implemented for relevant classes. objects as value types + references should be the default way of programming C++.
2. if you can't use a reference, because you want to specify a missing object, use C-pointer. by any way, strict the C-pointers to minimum and never let them manage anything. C-pointers are basically "viewers" to something and they can view "nothing" (or null). always think if you can replace C-pointer by C++ reference. if you *can* do it, *do* it.
3. use `std::unique_ptr` if for some reason you do need dynamic memory allocation, such as dynamic polymorphism. keep in mind that C++ works mostly on templates as static polymorphism, instead of the Java style inherit+override technique.
4. use `std::shared_ptr` rarely,and only when you're sure there are many owners, like an object which is referenced on different threads. `std::shared_ptr` should be used in extreme cases. always copy the shared pointer. never pass the shared pointer by reference.

Anyway, `new` , `new[]` , `delete` and `delete[]` are pretty much deprecated. only library writers should use them in very extreme cases. `std::make_` should be the only way allocating object on the heap, alongside the STL containers such as `std::vector` and `std::list`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I don't think the code you suggested is going to work for me.
See my post for updated main.

Comment: I think its worth noting that as of recent (C++11/14/17), its typically better practice to use 
`std::unique_ptr` followed by `std::shared_ptr` before using C-pointers. Both are type safe and much less likely to cause you problems when memory is mismanaged. Unique pointer shows better ownership of the data than C-pointers.

Comment: @AleksanderNaumenok The code isn't going to work for you if you are explicitly experimenting with Dynamic allocation, but keep reading. The lower portion accurately outlines the order in which you should use various allocation methods. 1 and 2 are out because your requirement is Dynamic allocation. That puts you at option 3, and 3 fits your case perfectly.

Comment: @RussleyShaw Recommend you re-read (and David Haim, an edit to clarify is probably in order). Point 2 discusses passing Automatic allocations by raw pointer if and only if using a reference cannot apply. It does not have anything to do with allocation. This should probably be point 1B with 1A being a discussion of passing using a reference.

Comment: @user4581301 if you take a look at the updated main, do you mean I should return a `std::unique_ptr`instead of a `* (raw pointer)`? I updated original post to reflect the suggested changes, please take a look when you have time.