# C++: How to push unique_ptr to deque?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr

In my project I need container that holds smart pointers to an data unit instances. I write the class (simple example):

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:

    void push(const T & param) 
    {
        m_deque.push_front(param);
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};
```

Than I want to push the one:

```
int main()
{

    Queue< std::unique_ptr<DataBox> > queue;

    std::unique_ptr<DataBox> d1(new DataBox(11));

    queue.push(d1);

    return 0;
}
```

And VS2017 compiler says that I can't do this:

`Error C2280 std::unique_ptr<DataBox,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

As I understand the reason of the error is attempt to make copy of unique_ptr. But if I change signature to:

`void push(T && param) {...}`

and the function call

`queue.push( std::move(d1) );`

I have this error again. So the question is - how should I implement `push()` that will move `unique_ptr` to the queue?

Comment: You likely just forgot the `std::move` for `m_deque.push_front(std::move(param));`

Comment: Unrelated: If C++14 or more recent is available and strong exception safety is desired, [consider using `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). Link to [some reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator) even if exception safety isn't required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to make it universal, so that `push` can take either l or r value you could try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <deque>
#include <utility>

class DataBox 
{
public:
    DataBox(int i) {}
};

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void push(U &&param)
    {
        m_deque.push_front(std::forward<T>(param));
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};      

int main()
{
    Queue<std::unique_ptr<DataBox>> queue;
    std::unique_ptr<DataBox> d1 = std::make_unique<DataBox>(11);
    std::unique_ptr<DataBox> d2 = std::make_unique<DataBox>(22);
    queue.push(d1);
    queue.push(std::move(d2));

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ixzEmN

Comment: Don't you mean `std::forward<U>` ?

Comment: normal, `std::move(d1)` should be used. currently, you move with your `std::forward<T>` unconditionally :/ [Demo](https://ideone.com/4zm4Kz)

Comment: @Jarod42 That is correct, the argument is always moved with this arrangement, but the argument is `unique_ptr` so I suppose this is what is wanted?

Answer (score 7):

You should modify your class to handle move only type:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
{
public:

    void push(const T & param) 
    {
        m_deque.push_front(param);
    }

    void push(T&& param) 
    {
        m_deque.push_front(std::move(param));
    }


private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};
```

With usage:

```
int main()
{
    Queue< std::unique_ptr<DataBox> > queue;

    std::unique_ptr<DataBox> d1(new DataBox(11));

    queue.push(std::move(d1));
}
```

Comment: What I need `void push(const T & param) ` for? Looks like universal reference is enough. Isn't it?

Comment: @Yura That is not a universal reference.  It is an rvalue reference.  Universal references are only formed from rvalue references to deduced template parameters, and `T` is not deduced in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options.

**Option 1: concise and usually fast**

```
template <typename T>
class Queue {
public:
    void push(T param) {
        m_deque.push_front(std::move(param));
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};
```

I would recommend this for most practical cases, since it's simple. However, if `T` isn't efficiently movable, it will do two copies instead of one.

**Option 2: always fast**

```
template <typename T>
class Queue {
public:
    void push(const T& param) {
        m_deque.push_front(param);
    }
    void push(T&& param) {
        m_deque.push_front(std::move(param));
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};
```

This is the most optimal solution, but it might be an overkill. If `T` is efficiently movable (and you should strive to make all types efficiently movable), then it does exactly the same amount of copies as option 1:

```
Queue<std::vector<int>> q;
std::vector<int> v;
q.push(v);             // one copy, both with option 1 and option 2
q.push(std::move(v));  // no copies, both with option 1 and option 2
```

However:

```
Queue<NotEfficientlyMovableType> q;
NotEfficientlyMovableType x;
q.push(x);             // one copy with option 2, two copies with option 1
q.push(std::move(x));  // same (so it doesn't really make sense)
```

**Option 3: concise, always fast, but has caveats**

```
template <typename T>
class Queue {
public:
    template <typename U>
    void push(U&& param)
    {
        m_deque.push_front(std::forward<T>(param));
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_deque;
};
```

With option 3 you only get to write one function and it always does the minimum number of copies (like option 2). However, it requires template argument deduction, which can break valid code. For example, this works with options 1 and 2, but not with option 3:

```
Queue<std::pair<int, int>> q;
q.push({1, 2});
```