# Assignment of unique_ptr inside member initializer list

Tags: c++

Say if I have this definition:

```
class A
{
    A();
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;   
};

class B {};
```

Is there a difference if I initialize `A` like:

```
A::A() : m_b(new B()) {}
```

vs.

```
A::A() : m_b(std::make_unique<B>()) {}
```

Additionally for the first case, can i be sure that I do not have to call `delete` explicitly?

Comment: `make_unique<B>` takes the arguments for constructing a `B`, not an object of `B`, so in your case it should be `A::A() : m_b(std::make_unique<B>()) {}`

Comment: This has been closed as duplicate, but it discusses not the general merits of using make_unique over new, but focuses on the special case of using it in member initializer lists.  This particular case has not been explicitly addressed in either of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37514509/5747415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22571202/5747415, https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/, https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/.  The benefits of make_unique that are listed for all the other scenarios do not seem to apply in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is style. Since use of operator `new` is now considered old fashioned `std::make_unique` is recommended.

For compiler there is no difference.

By the way is should be:

```cpp
A::A() : m_b{std::make_unique<B>()} {}
```

Also see
[CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.md at master · isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-make_unique)

> #### C.150: Use `make_unique()` to construct objects owned by `unique_ptr`s
>
> Reason
>
> `make_unique` gives a more concise statement of the construction. It also ensures exception safety in complex expressions.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<Foo> p {new Foo{7}};    // OK: but repetitive
>
> auto q = make_unique<Foo>(7);      // Better: no repetition of Foo
>
> // Not exception-safe: the compiler may interleave the computations of arguments as follows:
> //
> // 1. allocate memory for Foo,
> // 2. construct Foo,
> // 3. call bar,
> // 4. construct unique_ptr<Foo>.
> //
> // If bar throws, Foo will not be destroyed, and the memory-allocated for it will leak.
> f(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()), bar());
>
> // Exception-safe: calls to functions are never interleaved.
> f(make_unique<Foo>(), bar());
> ```