# std::make_unique with placement new

Tags: c++, new-operator, unique-ptr, variable-length-array, flexible-array-member

I'm trying to define a `Data` object that contains its size, followed by `size` bytes of data.

Something like:

```
struct Data {
    size_t size;
    char data[1];
    
    static void* operator new( std::size_t size, size_t dataSize ) {
        return ::operator new( size+dataSize-1 );
    }
    static void operator delete( void* data ){
        ::operator delete( data );
    }
    
    Data( size_t size ) : size(size) {
        std::memset( data, 0, size );
    }
};
```

This works, and I can allocate it with placement new:

```
Data* data = new (3) Data( 3 );
```

I'd like to create a `std::unique_ptr<Data>` and, [as good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514601/13255785), I'd prefer to use `std::make_uinque`, over a raw `new`.

Is it possible to call `std::make_unique<Data>` passing it the data for placement-new?

Any version of the C++ standard is fine.

Comment: `Data` is probably 16 bytes in size, consisting of 8 bytes `size`, 1 byte `data`, and 7 bytes padding, which is probably throwing off your calculations. I think `data` just flat out doesn't belong inside the class; you should get at the extra allocated space with something like `static_cast<std::byte*>(this) + sizeof(*this)`. Also, you should *really* think about making `Data`'s constructors `private` (`void horror() { Data d(10); }`... bone chilling), at which point `std::make_unique` doesn't even work anymore and you have to provide your own factory methods.

Comment: About the size of `Data` you're right. I can use `struct __attribute__((packed)) Data` though.

About the private constructor, I completely agree. I was trying to keep the example short here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this, because standard C++ doesn't provide any real support for VLAs/flexible array members. `make_unique` was written solely for either:

1. A single object of fixed size (it has no mechanism to provide information about the "real" size, it just uses `new`, which assumes `sizeof T` is correct and complete)
2. An array of objects of fixed size (by definition an array must have objects of fixed size, or indexing doesn't work)

I suppose in theory you could make your own version that supported quasi-flexible array members, but there is *zero* support for this in the C++ standard library. `std::make_unique` doesn't even have an allocator-aware variant; it's not going out of its way to support unusual use cases. `std::allocate_shared` (the allocator aware version of `std::make_shared`) might be forced to support this in ridiculous ways (you'd essentially need to write custom allocators that *also* knew how much extra memory an allocation request should provide), and [there's a proposal for an allocator-aware version of `std::make_unique`](https://wg21.link/P0211), but again, making this work would be an exercise in insanity.

You say "as good practice, I'd prefer to use `std::make_unique`, over a raw `new`", but flexible array members in C++ are already bad practice; there is essentially zero support for them because they break all sorts of assumptions that much of the C++ language and library rely on. If you must do it, write your own factory methods to perform the work; sure, using raw `new` is frowned on, but confining it to a single API in your code that guarantees the result is a managed pointer before passing it outside that API limits the "damage".