# Why is move constructor called when doing assignment?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a sample implementation of std::unique_ptr. Here is the code:

```
include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class UniquePtr
{
public:
  explicit UniquePtr(T * ptr)
    :m_ptr(ptr)
  {};

  UniquePtr(UniquePtr const & other) = delete;
  UniquePtr& operator=(UniquePtr const & other) = delete;

  explicit UniquePtr(UniquePtr && other)
  {
    m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
    other.m_ptr = nullptr;
  }

  UniquePtr & operator=(UniquePtr && other)
  {
    std::cout << "Move assignment called " << std::endl;
    m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
    other.m_ptr = nullptr;
  }

  ~UniquePtr()
  {
    delete m_ptr;
  }

  T& operator*()
  {
    return *m_ptr;
  }

  T& operator->()
  {
    return m_ptr;
  }

private:
  T * m_ptr = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
  UniquePtr<int> t(new int(3));
  t= UniquePtr<int>(new int(4));

  std::cout << *t << std::endl;
}
```

This code compiles and I'm able to see the value 4 in the output even after deleting the default assignment and copy constructor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `t= UniquePtr<int>(new int(4));` is a `move` in this case.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics/11540204#11540204

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not returning `*this` from your move assignment operator. That's the only thing that you are doing wrong. Can you explain why you believe that the move constructor is getting called?

Comment: @ChrisMM, that's what I also thought. But why is that? Also what happens to the pointer which is pointed to by the first unique ptr?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, because that line gets printed. I added `return *this` but I still get the same result

Comment: The only line that prints anything, in the shown code, is the line in the move ***assignment*** operator. Not the move ***constructor***. Nothing gets printed in the move constructor. Pop quiz: what is `operator=`? Is it: 1) the move constructor, or 2) the move assignment operator?

Comment: Please read the linked page. The answer on it actually discusses `unique_ptr` example, including what happens to the `new int(3)` (it gets leaked)

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. You're using a move assignment operator. So, why don't you expect a 4 in the ouptut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the assignment, move is called because the `UniquePtr<int>(new int(4))` is constructing a temporary object, and in this case the compiler tries to use the move assignment if possible, else it would fall back to the copy assignment, which is deleted.

```
UniquePtr<int> t(new int(3));
t= UniquePtr<int>(new int(4)); // move assignment because temporary
auto k = t; // copy assignment since t is not temporary and so does not compile.
```

As commented, the move assignment is not returning `*this`, you should enable all warnings. Also the last `operator->` has a syntax error, it returns a pointer but expects a reference.

Additionally, your code has a major issue, in case of exceptions you could have a memory leak. Suppose you write something like:

```
class Banana
{ ... }

void eatBanana(UniquePtr<Banana> banana, int amountToEat);
int computeAmount();

eatBanana(UniquePtr<Banana>(new Banana(3)), computeAmount());
```

If, for any reason, the `computeAmount()` function throws an exception, then the memory allocated by `new` could never be released, because `computeAmount()` could be executed between `new` and the constructor of the `UniquePtr`. For this reason, we normally use `std::make_unique()`.

You should implement your own version of `make_unique()` and use it, it's trival, see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Here more information about the issues and the solution:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch04.html

Comment: You should clarify that `auto k = t;` won't compile.

Comment: it is a temporary object but the object still gets leaked, right? is there anyway to avoid that? Maybe this is not a real-world use-case anyway..

Comment: *If for any reason the constructor of Banana throws an exception, then the memory allocated by new will never be released* is incorrect.  The leak scenario is a bit more nuanced, q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514601/4641116

Comment: Yes, just after writing the example I realized it wasn't correct, fixed quickly.