# Using std::make_unique with the GetProfileBinary function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

I have seen this answer ([Advantages of using std::make_unique over new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator)) where it states:

> Don't use `make_unique` if you need a custom deleter *or are adopting a raw pointer from elsewhere*.

This is is my code:

```
void CAutomaticBackupSettingsPage::GetLastBackupDate(COleDateTime& rBackupDate)
{
    DATE* pDatTime = nullptr;
    UINT uSize;

    theApp.GetProfileBinary(_T("Options"), _T("BackupLastBackupDate"), pointer_cast<LPBYTE*>(&pDatTime), &uSize);
    if (uSize == sizeof(DATE))
        rBackupDate = *pDatTime;
    else
        rBackupDate = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

    delete[] pDatTime;
    pDatTime = nullptr;
}
```

Code analysis gives me two warnings:

[image]

and

[image]

The latter warning suggests I use `std::make_unique` but since my pointer data is returned from the [`GetProfileBinary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#getprofilebinary) call, and given the statement in the related question, does that mean I should not use `std::make_unique`? I admit it is something I have not done before.

---

The useage of `GetProfileBinary` clearly states:

> `GetProfileBinary` allocates a buffer and returns its address in `*ppData`. *The caller is responsible for freeing the buffer using `delete[]`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pDateTime` is supposed to be `nullptr`, and `GetProfileBinary` handles the allocation. Code Analysis mistakenly thinks you forgot the allocation.

It does need to check for success before calling `delete[]`. We can't use `delete[]pDatTime` because `pDatTime` is not an array. But `GetProfileBinary` allocates using `new BYTE[size]`, so we need to cast back to `BYTE`.

You can also add a `NULL` check before reading `pDatTime`, that might make Code Analysis happy.

```
if (pDatTime && uSize == sizeof(DATE))
    rBackupDate = *pDatTime;
else
    rBackupDate = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
if(pDatTime) delete[](BYTE*)pDatTime;
```

You can use `std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> cleanup((BYTE*)pDatTime)` for deletion, but this has to be after `GetProfileBinary` is called.

Example:

```
DATE* pDatTime = nullptr;
GetProfileBinary(_T("Options"), _T("BackupLastBackupDate"), (LPBYTE*)(&pDatTime), &uSize);
std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> cleanup((BYTE*)pDatTime); //automatic delete

if (pDatTime && uSize == sizeof(DATE))
    rBackupDate = *pDatTime;
else
    rBackupDate = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();

//pDatTime = NULL; <- Error when used with unique_ptr
...
//pDatTime is deleted later, when `cleanup` goes out of scope
```

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMole, I think I fixed it, the compile errors anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Those warnings are now removed if I use both of your tweaks. To prevent the C style cast warning I have used: `std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> cleanup(pointer_cast<BYTE*>(pDatTime));`. Question 1: Is the final line in my function now obsolete (`pDatTime = nullptr;`) since we are calling this `Cleanup` method? Question 2: In my `GetProfileBinary` call I cast to `LPBYTE*` but in your subsequent code suggestions we use `BYTE*` and `BYTE[]` respectively. I guess this does not matter.

Comment: 1: You don't need `pDatTime = nullptr;` after it has been deleted, because it's a local variable and you are exiting the function. 2: Your call to `GetProfileBinary` is correct, `LPBYTE*` is expected. In  a different place, I used `BYTE*`, that relates to how memory is allocated inside `GetProfileBinary`. Also be careful how `std::unique_ptr` is used, the compiler may do weird optimization and break it. If you use it, show it in your question.

Comment: @and `cleanup` is not a method. It is an object of type `std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]>`. It has a non-trivial destructor that runs as the object goes out of scope. It is the destructor that performs the resource cleanup. I'm confused why code analysis doesn't flag that as a *"variable is never used"* issue.

Comment: I have only used `std::unique_ptr` where you suggested ...

Comment: That's a good point, using `unique_ptr...(pDatTime)` followed by `pDatTime = nullptr` is an error. But it is okay to put `pDatTime = nullptr` after `delete[]...`, in that case it doesn't accomplish anything, but it won't cause an error either. See edit.

Comment: But it is safe to use my point_cast inside your cleanup call I assume? It is a wrapper for reinterpret_cast. Else I get code analysis warning about c style cast.

Comment: Yes, you can replace that with `reinterpret_cast`.